# Avoid JSON escaping in Eex

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to pass some Elixir data into Javascript serializing it with Jsex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myData = <%= JSEX.encode! my_data %>;
</script>
```

But the output appears to be escaped, like [&Quot;a&Quot;,1].
Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: Are you using a framework, maybe Phoenix?

Comment: @p11y Yeah, I'm on Phoenix right now. Your solution works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that in Phoenix now, using the following tuple does the trick :

```
<%= {:safe, JSEX.encode!(my_data)} %>
```

http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Template.HTML.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Phoenix, you can use [`Phoenix.Html.safe`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/29c16debb5d8c5f823c179b9627707f0b1e71ec3/lib/phoenix/html.ex#L12-L13) to prevent escaping. It is [imported automatically](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/29c16debb5d8c5f823c179b9627707f0b1e71ec3/lib/phoenix/view.ex#L46) in views:

```
<%= safe JSEX.encode!(my_data) %>
```